# Возвращение String из функции Int через рекурсию Swift

Tags: swift, рекурсия

Необходимо из функции типа Int, которая возвращает значение String получить фиксированную последовательность чисел от n до 1 рекурсивным методом. Подскажите, пожалуйста как реализовать. Получилось сделать только через массив, который сортирован от 1 до n.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: 1) читать легче; 2) можно копировать; 3) поиск работает. Исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: В каком виде строка должна возвращаться? типа "5 4 3 2 1"?